# Java Staircase is printing in wrong direction (hackerrank)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This solution to the staircase prints the correct output, but in the opposite direction. Any idea how to alter this solution to get the desired result?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

// Complete the staircase function below.
static void staircase(int n) {
int counter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        //for (int k=0; k<n-k-1;k++)
        //  {
        //      System.out.println("");
        //  }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("#");
        counter++;

        for(int j=0; j<counter-1;j++) 
        {

            System.out.print("#");
        }
    }   
}

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    staircase(n);

    scanner.close();
}
}
```

Input:

```
6
```

Expected output:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Actual Output:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
```

It's for a hackerrank easy challenge. I just want to be able to use my approach that I discovered instead of a solution I find online. Thanks!

Comment: Before printing a `#`, print `n - i - 1` spaces.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Could you provide a little more clarification where I should put that inside of my solution? above both of the for loops? in place of one of the for loops?

Comment: Try putting it after `System.out.print("\n");`, in addition to what you have.

Comment: Don't write, never present undocumented&uncommented code.

Comment: There are spaces in the output, you're not printing spaces anywhere.

Comment: The `scanner.skip` in your code seems entirely pointless, and very hard to read.

Comment: @Dukeling It's part of the template hackerrank.com gives you. normally on these challenges you don't touch the main outside of changing some parameter variables if necessary for your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to make two changes:

First you have to add a loop that will print spaces. If you start the loop at `n` and loop until more than or equal to `i`, while subtracting, this will print the correct amount of spaces.

Second, you need to have the newline at the end of the loop:

```
static void staircase(int n) {

   int counter=0;
   for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
   {
       counter++;
       for(int k=n; k>= i;k--)
       {
           System.out.print(" "); 
       } 
       for(int j=0; j<=counter-1;j++) 
       {
           System.out.print("#");
       }

       System.out.print("\n");
   }
}
```

***Output:***

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Also just a note on your code. It is bad practice to close `System.in`. The general rule is that if you did not open a resource, you should not close it.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use extra `counter` variable. Just try this:

```
static void printStaircase(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; ++j) {
            System.out.print('\u00a0'); // nbsp
        }
        for (int j = n - i + 1; j <= n; ++j) {
            System.out.print('#');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other proposition :

```
static void staircase(int n) {
    for(int i=n; i> 0; i--) {
        String s= "";
        for(int j=1; j<=n-i+1; j++) s+="#";
        System.out.printf("%"+n+"s\n", s);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
 static void staircase(int n) {
     String p = "";
  for(int i = 0 ; i< n ; i++){
      p = p + "#";
      System.out.printf("%"+n+"s\n", p);
     
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple and Short way to do this-

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
      System.out.println(new String(new char[n-i]).replace("\0", " ") + new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", "#"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And another way

```
fun staircase(n: Int): Unit {
    for (i in 1..n) {
        print(" ".repeat(n-i))
        println("#".repeat(i))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void staircase(int n) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        counter++;
        for (int x = n-1; x >= i; x--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= counter - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        if (i != n) {
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.print("");
        }
    }
}
```